# Is this relationship creepy?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

According to [this XKCD comic](https://xkcd.com/314/), there is a formula to determine whether or not the age gap in a relationship is "creepy". This formula is defined as:

```
(Age/2) + 7
```

being the minimum age of people you can date.

Therefore a relationship is creepy if either of the people in said relationship are younger than the minimum age of the other.

Given the age of two people, can you output whether or not that relationship is creepy?

#### Rules

1. Your program should take two integers as input, the age of both people in the relationship. These can be taken in any reasonable format.
2. Your program must then output a truthy or falsy value describiing whether or not the relationship is "creepy" (Truthy = Creepy).
3. Standard loopholes are not allowed.
4. This puzzle is Code Golf, so the answer with the shortest source code in bytes wins

#### Test Cases

```
40, 40    - Not Creepy
18, 21    - Not Creepy
80, 32    - Creepy
15, 50    - Creepy
47, 10000 - Creepy
37, 38    - Not Creepy
22, 18    - Not Creepy
```

Comment: How should `age/2` be rounded? Probably up if the exact half is supposed to be the minimum? `17,21` would make a good test case.

Comment: @MartinEnder The value is a minimum, so do not round at all. It doesn't have to be an integer.

Comment: @FishProHD can we require a certain input order (i.e. largest first)

Comment: You could also add `13, 13 - Creepy`.

Comment: 47, 10000 is an... interesting combination. I would also like to point out that according to this formula, it is creepy for Doctor Who to date any human.

Comment: @DavidConrad - well yeah. its basically beastiality on his part....

Comment: I hate to be a puritan about it but 17-20 is very-easily creepy.

Comment: Would you mind updating the accepted answer?

Comment: Done! Sorry about the delay didn't check it in a while.

Comment: An important test case is, for example, `21, 29 - Creepy`. If you do integer division you get it wrong.

Comment: This post is like 5 months old @Max

Comment: Had to take a second look after seeing the title to make sure I wasn't on IPS...

Comment: any age below 14 is creepy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
H+7>ṚṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99D29zu4c5ZD3c2/P//38RcR8HQAAgA)

Seemingly different algorithm than Comrade's.

Comment: Well, its the same *now*... ;p

Comment: @Draco18s It was always the same with the earlier 05AB1E submission though.

Answer (score 23):

## NAND gates, 551

[image: 16-bit creepiness calculator]
Created with [Logisim](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/)

Same principle as [my other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141497/73884), but takes 2-byte signed inputs, so it can handle `47, 10000`. Works for ALL test cases!

This is not optimal for the given test cases, as 10000 can be expressed with only 15 of the 16 bits, but it works for any ages in the range [-32768, 32768). Note that any negative age will return `1`.

Inputs on left (no particular order, 1-bit on top). Output in lower right.

Answer (score 17):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda x:max(x)/2+7>min(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQYZWbWKFRoalvpG1ul5uZB2T@T8svUqhQyMxTiI42MdBRMDGI1Yk2tNBRMDIEMcyhDAuglLERSMRUR8EUpMYEKGVoAARAtjGQbWwRG2vFpVBQlJlXolGhkwY0W/P/fwA)
The input is a list with both ages

Comment: Had the same before I read existing answers. +1

Comment: It appears you could actually assume a tuple where it's always (younger,older) - just asked OP - wonder what he'll say.

Comment: @rm-vanda I asked earlier, you can't assume

Answer (score 16):

## NAND gates, <strike>274</strike> 262

Original:
[image]

Better:
[image]
Created with [Logisim](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/)

This takes two inputs on the left as 1-byte signed integers, with the 1-bit at the top. Output is in the lower left; the truthy and falsey here should be obvious.

Works for all test cases except `47, 10000`, so I guess this is technically not a valid answer. However, the [oldest person on (reliable) record](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/oldest-person) was 122, so 8 bits (max 127) will work for any scenario ever possible to this point. I'll post a new answer (or should I edit this one?) when I finish the 16-bit version.

[16-bit version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141585/73884) is done!

You'll notice some vertical sections of the circuit. The first one (from the left) determines which input is greater. The next two are multiplexers, sorting the inputs. I then add `11111001` (-7) to the lesser in the fourth section, and I conclude by comparing twice this to the greater input. If it is less, the relationship is creepy. Since I shift the bits to double, I must take into account the unused bit of `lesser-7`. If this is a `1`, then `lesser-7` is negative, and the younger of the two is no older than six. Creepy. I finish with an OR gate, so if either creepiness test returns `1`, the entire circuit does.

If you look closely, you'll see that I used <strike>seven</strike> one constant<strike>s</strike> (hardcoding the `11111011` and the trailing `0`). I did this because Logisim requires at least one value going in for a logic gate to produce an output. However, each time a constant is used, two NAND gates ensure a `1` value regardless of the constant.

-12 gates thanks to [me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73884/scrooble)!

Comment: Noticed an obvious optimization. If you point it out before I edit, I'll still credit you!

Answer (score 15):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
;7+R‹Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f2lw76FHDzqj//6NNDHRMDGIB) or [Try all test](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9W6fLf2lw76FHDzqj/lUqH91spKLmkF9sbGhfruqkr2NdmKjkXpaYWVCrpHF6t5JdfogDj/o@ONjHQMTGI1Yk2tNAxMgTSFgY6xkYgvqmOKUjcxFzH0AAIgExjcx1jCyBtZKRjCKINjXUMjWNjAQ)

```
         # Implicit Input: an array of the ages
;        # Divide both ages by 2
 7+      # Add 7 to both ages
   R     # Reverse the order of the ages
         #    this makes the "minimum age" line up with the partner's actual age
    ‹    # Check for less than the input (vectorized)
     Z   # Push largest value in the list
```

Comment: As a C programmer I agree that 2 is truthy.

Comment: @gmatht This should always return either 0 or 1, never 2.

Comment: [13,13] is doubly creepy.

Comment: @gmatht I guess that would be double. I didn't think about numbers that small. It's still truthy though.

Comment: @Riley `2` is not truthy, see [this](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f2lw76FHDTn@uTKWSotKSjEqlw6uV0hJziiuV/v@PNjTWMTSOBQA "05AB1E – Try It Online").

Comment: @Okx `2` is not truthy, we shouldn't use `__` to determine truthiness, we should use `i1ë0}`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I don't understand.

Comment: @Okx Riley probably assumed `2` is truthy, or used `__`, while `_` considers `2` to be truthy, while consensus says it must behave like truthy on if statements, so `i1ë0}` is the perfect truthiness checker to use here.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer May I say again that should use isn't in a golfer's dictionary? Whatever works, works.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I'm not using `__` to check for truthyness, I'm using it to translate 0->0, 1->1, and 2->1 which will make the output match the if statement definition of truthy/falsy.

Comment: @Riley I wasn't talking about the use of `__` here.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Okay. I guess I'm just confused about what you guys are talking about.

Comment: @Riley We were talking about how you assumed `2` is truthy at first, and a potential way so that you never face the issue again. Coincidentally, it involved the use of `__` too (since `Ā` was added after the challenge).

Comment: @Riley `Z` or `P` works :P.

Answer (score 9):

## C#, 22 bytes

```c#
n=>m=>n<m/2+7|m<n/2+7;
```

Comment: I'm not much of a C# programmer, but is the final semicolon required as part of the function?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire It's just invalid syntax if it's omitted; this is an anonymous function

Answer (score 8):

## C, 29 bytes

```
#define f(a,b)a/2+7>b|b/2+7>a
```

How it works:

- `#define f(a,b)` defines a macro function `f` that takes two untyped arguments.
- `a/2+7>b` checks if the first age divided by two plus seven is larger than the second age.
- `b/2+7>a` checks if the second age divided by two plus seven is larger than the first age.
- If either of the above values are true, return 1 (creepy). Otherwise, return 0 (not creepy).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDNCoJAFEb38xQX28zUiPMnSlEt2vcOo2m4SMUMjOrZ7aaEhITezcCZM99lvtg9x3HbektiBAcjAMeFY1HDoUqS8k5kyEHJEQ7R1qrHX9Pn4IsfZAIOUuAMSCPS4ShPKTTHeOkRsjglaZYnkFLLI2Y9tQp20TPqTjtc11VRpLRhQJu90z931s6Q5TBysVlOGXmQz54sr8HCFmPx50awTUfLW32lfZRlyDrYa9iEktMaNqPVjDSf@zOWYoNdgdMmFqvDaQ2Llv@0V9u@AQ)

Comment: you should flip the comparison, it should be like `>b` not `<b`

Comment: Quote "being the minimum age" means you have to check if `age >= min`, also you need AND instead of OR, since both sides has to satisfy in order for it to not be creepy, test case "47, 10000 - Creepy"

Comment: okay I've fixed the error, but the logic is wrong, it return true, [tio.run](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@6@cmZecU5qSqmBTXJKSma@XYcfFpZySmpaZl6qQppGok6SZqG@kbW6TVJMEphO5uHITM/M0yvIzUzS5qrk4M/NKFBIVbBVMzK0hnCQgx9AACKD8ZCAfYhJQoKAIKJSmkWyvVFJUmqpkpZSWmFOcqgSUqv3/HwA)

Comment: @Khaled.K Hm, fixed.

Comment: @Tas [nope.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6912/61563)

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the link

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 21 bytes

```
a=>b=>a<b/2+7|b<a/2+7
```

Returns 0 for not creepy, 1 for creepy.

```js
f=a=>b=>a<b/2+7|b<a/2+7

console.log(f(40)(40));
console.log(f(18)(21));
console.log(f(80)(32));
console.log(f(15)(50));
console.log(f(47)(10000));
console.log(f(37)(38));
console.log(f(22)(18));
```

Comment: Save a byte with currying: `a=>b=>` instead of `(a,b)=>`, call with `f(40)(40)`.

Comment: @StephenS, thank you, learned something new!

Comment: No problem, I learned it when someone told me the same thing :) it only works with two parameters though, after that it's not worth it.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @djhurio*

```r
any(rev(a<-scan())<a/2+7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzGvUqMotUwj0Ua3ODkxT0NT0yZR30jbXPO/kZGCocV/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic, <s>20</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
max(2Ans<14+max(Ans
```

-10 bytes by using a list and part of Timtech's suggestion

-1 byte using lirtosiast's suggestion

Takes in a list of two ages, "{40,42}:prgmNAME"

Returns 1 for 'creepy' and 0 for 'not creepy'.

Comment: Does TI-BASIC automatically close parentheses at a testing-symbol (`<` `<=` `=` `!=` `>=` `>`)?

Comment: @Zacharý No, TI-Basic only closes parentheses at the end of a line or a colon.

Comment: Oh, whoops I forgot that the input was being taken as a list of numbers!

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, <s>74</s> 45 bytes

First Code Golf, probably terrible.

29 byte reduction by @Phoenix

```python
lambda a,b:0 if(a/2)+7>b or(b/2)+7>a else 1
```

Comment: Hi, please be sure to properly format your code using the markdown system.

Comment: don't worry, someone beat me to it, ill fix it though

Comment: You can get rid of some of the spaces there :)

Comment: Also, `lambda a,b:0 if(a/2)+7>b or(b/2)+7>a else 1` should work and is shorter by a lot.

Comment: i think the space before `if` can be left out as well as the one after `else`

Comment: `lambda a,b:0if a/2+7>b or b/2+7>a else1`...

Comment: `lambda a,b:a/2+7>b or b/2+7>a`. Abandon the burden of those pesky `1`s and `0`s and embrace the power of `True`/`False`!

Answer (score 5):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 20 bytes

```
O`.+
^1{7}(1+)¶1\1\1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#HcbLCYAwEEXR/atDIZpBZvJhpgsXboNkYRdiWxZgYzGEC5czu1ouj2nFUantdfM45dbHiV@@V0qvtcSUGKIUBGLj3WE4wJhid6bMSErCzIhK0X4)

Input is in unary with a linefeed between the two numbers. Output is `0` (not creepy) or `1` (creepy).

#### Explanation

```
O`.+
```

Sort the two numbers, so we know that the larger one is second.

```
^1{7}(1+)¶1\1\1
```

Call the smaller age `a` and the larger age `b`. We first capture `a-7` in group `1`. Then we try to match `2*(a-7)+1` in `b`, which means `b >= 2*(a-7)+1` or `b >= 2*(a-7)` or `b/2+7 > a` which is the criterion for a creepy relationship.

Answer (score 4):

## GNU APL 1.2, 23 bytes

Defines a function that takes two arguments and prints 1 if creepy, 0 if not.

```
∇A f B
(A⌊B)<7+.5×A⌈B
∇
```

#### Explanation

`∇` begins and ends the function
`A f B` is the function header; function is named `f` and takes two arguments, `A` and `B` (functions in APL can be monadic - taking one argument - or dyadic - taking two arguments)
`A⌊B` is `min(A,B)` and `A⌈B` is `max(A,B)`
APL is evaluated right-to-left, so parentheses are needed to ensure proper precedence

The other operators are self explanatory.

Code might be golf-able, I'm still new to code-golf.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Wow, nice, GNU APL, haven't seen that in a while.

Comment: Also, it's possible to take the arguments as a list: `f X` then `(⌊/X)<7+.5×⌈/X`. IIRC you can remove the newline between the second and third lines.

Comment: @Zacharý Yes, anonymous lambdas are possible. They are not supported by this version of GNU APL and the newer one does not compile on Mac. Some of my other answers use APL 1.7 because I test them on Ubuntu. I have not used lambdas (might fix them later) because I'm still pretty new to APL.

Comment: Try out ngn-apl. It's open-source like GNU APL, but in all honesty it's better.

Comment: Doesn't GNU APL use UTF-8? Anyway, in Dyalog APL, you can write this tacitly as [`⌊<7+.5×⌈`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///37koNbWg8lHbhEc9XTbm2nqmh6c/6un4/9/EQMHQQsECSJoqmJgrGJsrGBkpQBQrAOWMDBWMjRRMgdIGQKBgbAFUDQA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám I was not aware that you could give arguments implicitly; that’s pretty neat.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

```
f=a=>b=>b>a?f(b)(a):b>a/2+7
```

No currying (call like `f(a,b)` instead of `f(a)(b)`)

```
f=(a,b)=>b>a?f(b,a):b>a/2+7
```

If `b > a`, swap parameters and retry. Otherwise, check. Currying doesn't save any bytes because of the recursive call.

```js
f=a=>b=>b>a?f(b)(a):b>a/2+7

console.log(f(18)(22))
console.log(f(22)(18))
console.log(f(18)(21))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, <s>26</s> 24 Bytes

Cell formula that takes input as numbers from cell range `A1:B1` and output a boolean value representing creepiness to the formula cell

```vba
=OR(A1/2+7>B1,B1/2+7>A1)
```

**Old Version, 26 Bytes**

```vba
=MAX(A1:B1)/2+7>MIN(A1:B1)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 21 bytes

```
a->b->a/2+7>b|b/2+7>a
```

Absolutely not original.

### Testing

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#TU/LasJAFN3nKw6BQNLGaTIqBm3TRaHQTRFciovJS6bEScjcCGLz7XZMYnU29zzu44w81FVD@BFHwVqSJStalZKsFHtaWVZaCq2xTvch53Me4GwBmgTJFF@KPsfWV4PXTZ7JVFAeo8AbLmISJ5NYvPDnRZz8Jn0Vl5WZr9ukNPPjmmMlMxyEVO6GGqn22x1Es9defwqQirY7o1GuSZu9gwqcZ4GPWdD5Nx5GPnh455Hxp/zBn/uYP/TPFj7CwLy7NDXSNLpzzk1L1PW0W/WlqBq4faY@0XLI5f3H2pw05QdWtcRq8xsqXNvJfDgZJnC0o2y/n9gGuxGEBhRM1HV5ckfHY1fgjraHd9gfTZ7XJxtL2N8VIR2oN2S6Buys7vIH)

```
import java.util.function.*;

public class Pcg122520 {
  static IntFunction<IntPredicate> f = a->b->a/2+7>b|b/2+7>a;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] tests = {
      {40, 40},
      {18, 21},
      {80, 32},
      {15, 50},
      {47, 10000},
      {37, 38},
      {22, 18}
    };
    for (int[] test: tests) {
      System.out.printf("%d, %d - %s%n", test[0], test[1], f.apply(test[0]).test(test[1]) ? "Creepy" : "Not creepy");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning "_Absolutely not original._". Almost no one else does, while they are almost all the same. And I took the liberty of adding a TIO-link from your test code. Not sure why you always add a test code, but not a [TIO-link](https://tio.run/nexus)?.. :)

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I sometimes do add one, sometimes not. It depends on whether I have my IDE open or closed. It's as simple as that! :P Also, I show the test code in order for people to understand what makes this lambda valid. :)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 31 bytes

`lambda a,b:abs(a-b)>min(a,b)-14`

Not much shorter than the other python submissions, but I found a slightly different way to check for creepiness. I noticed that the acceptable difference between ages is equal to min - 14. This follows from algebraically rearranging the formula.

```
min = (max/2) + 7
min - 7 = max/2
2*min - 14 = max

dif = max - min
max = dif + min

2*min - 14 = dif + min
min - 14 = dif
```

This let me solve without needing two constants, and also without needing to use both max and min, instead using abs(a-b). From a golfing perspective I only got one byte less than @nocturama's solution, but I used a slightly different formula to do it.

Comment: Surely this fails on [37,53] (not in the test suite but) within the (x/2)+7 spirit of this fairway

Comment: @AlexxRoche Nope, when given [37,53] as [a,b], the calculation should become

`abs(37 - 53) > min(37, 53) - 14 = abs(-16) > 37 - 14 = 16 > 23 = False`

This is the correct answer, because according to (x/2) + 7, the minimum age for 53 is `53/2 + 7 = 26.5 + 7 = 33.5`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 11 bytes

```
max/2+7>min
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYk7DoAgEAV7T0HvEmHBSOVFjIUlRsEPRAvP7rr4qpl5806DVSCsGqEatAOBupDjZvBvLYj2f20HQiteEcNiXCFEzm58aJ3uBuuuX30geuOWfAwnSRnyskgftpxYjumSMSeWDw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Mathics](http://mathics.github.io/), 16 bytes

```
Max@#/2+7<Min@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfN7HCQVnfSNvcxjczz0FZ7X9AUWZeiUNadLWJgY6CiYECENTGcsFFDS10FIwM0UUtgGqNjTDUmuoomGKYYGKuo2BoAAQoosZAUWMLiNr/AA)

-2 bytes thanks to [@GregMartin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56178/greg-martin)

True for not creepy, false for creepy.

```
            (* Argument: A list of integers     *)
Max@#       (* The maximum of the input         *)
 /2+7       (* Divided by 2, plus 7             *)
  <         (* Is less than?                    *)
   Min@#    (* The minimum of the input         *)
    &       (* Anonymous function               *)
```

Comment: Save `2` bytes by taking the ages as a list: `Max@#/2+7<Min@#&`

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 10 bytes

```
2min(Ans)-14≤max(Ans
```

List input from `Ans`, outputs `1` if "creepy" or `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

### SAS, 77 bytes

```
%macro t(a,b);%put%eval(%sysfunc(max(&a,&b))/2+7>%sysfunc(min(&a,&b)));%mend;
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 50 bytes

```
@if %1 gtr %2 %0 %2 %1
@cmd/cset/a"%1*2-14-%2>>31
```

Outputs `-1` for creepy, `0` for not creepy.

Since Batch only has integer arithmetic I have to work in units of half years.

Comment: +1 for the `%0 %2 %1` and bypassing interget aritmetic.

Answer (score 2):

## [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org/), <strike>44</strike>  27 bytes

-17 from looking at [daniero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122839/69490)'s answer in Ruby.

```
def a(a)7+a.max/2>a.min end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/crystal#@5@SmqaQqJGoaa6dqJebWKFvZAekM/MUUvNSuApKS4qBktEmBjomBrGacL6hhY6RIRLfwkDH2AhZ3lTHFFm9ibmOoQEQIAkZm@sYWyDxjYx0DIH8//8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 15 bytes

```perl6
{.max/2+7>.min}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#ZY7LaoNAFIb38xT/IlSto@MtjVQSCt131aUQUp2C4GWaGUtC8In6Fn0xezS9UDybw3znY/6/1xLvd36RseaMm6IrJbbjxW8OJxG5m53fVO0w0unBSG2wRV21UtsOCer@woCVIOhrVVfGFsj1LSzPmrdwMrq7nx@rwC@65sUWeekKh2MVQr7BejxKqc4WvfdsYD31eKaIjKn60MKd8zL22h2/o70d7LxqVW94Lk9KFkaWPC@lLhxMRSqNqb09K5Ty62By2DAmAUcSgMbDU2dwzWdhyhGFC5ySHUdX/GOuOdbBP5RsOMKA5g/FhOJ08V8UkbnAXw)

### Expanded

```perl6
{ # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
  # (input is a List)

  .max / 2 + 7
  >
  .min
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 - <s>32</s> 27 bytes

Unable to comment, but I got a slightly shorter answer than the other Python 3 solution:

```
lambda *a:min(a)<max(a)/2+7
```

-5 thanks to @Cyoce!

Comment: you can remove the space in `lambda *a`

Answer (score 2):

## **FORTH 96 Bytes**

```
: C 2DUP > -1 = IF SWAP THEN 2 /  7 +  SWAP > -1 = IF ."  CREEPY " ELSE ." NOT CREEPY " THEN ;
```

**Output:**

```
40 40 c NOT CREEPY  ok
18 21 c
18 21 c NOT CREEPY  ok
80 32 c
80 32 c  CREEPY  ok
15 50 c
15 50 c  CREEPY  ok
47 10000 c
47 10000 c  CREEPY  ok
37 38 c
37 38 c NOT CREEPY  ok
22 18 c
22 18 c NOT CREEPY  ok
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `G`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
½7+r<
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0krtS7IKlpSVpuhbLDu011y6yWVKclFwMFVqwzNBUR8HUAMIDAA)

Port of Riley's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
½7+r<  # Implicit input
½      # Halve each value
 7+    # Add seven to each
   r   # Reverse the list
    <  # Vectorised less than
       # Get the maximum
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 16 bytes

```
{(x&y)<7+-2!x|y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1qjQq1S08ZcW9dIsaKmsvZ/goGVCrqgnoaJgYKJgSYXdklDUwVTA83/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 5 bytes

```
Ṁä7+≥
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6Fqse7mw4vMRc-1Hn0iXFScnFUOEFN62iTQx0TAxiuaINLXSMDIG0hYGOsRGIb6pjChI3MdcxNAACINPYXMfYAkgbGekYWsRCjAAA)

Returns `True` for not creepy, `False` for creepy.

```
Ṁ        Get the maximum of the input
 ä       Divide it by 2
  7+     Add 7
    ≥    Is every element of the input greater than or equal to that?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 8 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
<+7÷2⊃↥↧
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgPCs3w7cy4oqD4oal4oanCgpmIDQwIDQwCmYgMTggMjEKZiA4MCAzMgpmIDE1IDUwCmYgNDcgMTAwMDAKZiAzNyAzOApmIDIyIDE4CmYgMTMgMTMKZiAyMSAyOQo=)

```
<+7÷2⊃↥↧    input: two ages as two separate stack items
     ⊃↥↧    push max and min of the two ages
 +7÷2       max / 2 + 7
<           is greater than min?
```

Answer (score 1):

## Fourier, 37 bytes

```
oI~AI~B>A{1}{A~SA~BS~B}A/2+7>B{1}{@o}
```

[**Try it on FourIDE!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/editor/?code=b0l-QUl-Qj5BezF9e0F-U0F-QlN-Qn1BLzIrNz5CezF9e0BvfQ)

Takes two numbers as input. Will golf later.

Comment: It doesn't need to output a string like that, can be truthy or falsy

Comment: Nice golf. That was quick.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

Returns `true` for "creepy" and `false` for not.

```
wV /2+7>UmV
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=d1YgLzIrNz5VbVY=&input=ODAsMzI=)

---

### Explanation

```
      :Implicit input of first integer U
wV    :Get the maximum of U and the second integer V
/2+7  :Divide by 2 & add 7
>     :Check if the result is greater than...
UmV   :the minimum of the two integers.
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 29 Bytes

prints 1 for creepy, nothing for Not creepy

```
<?=max($_GET)/2+7>min($_GET);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgSi0qyi@KL0otyC8qycxL16hzjffzD/F0dtW05lKJd3cNsY02NNMxNI@1trf7b2Nvm5tYoQEW19Q30ja3y83Mg3Kt////mpevm5yYnJEKAA)

Comment: As I understand the rules this fails on [34,19]

Answer (score 1):

## J, 10 bytes

```
<.<7+2%~>.
```

Outputs `1` for not creepy, `0` for creepy

#### Explanation

```
<.          NB. the minimum
  >         NB. is greater than
    7+2%~>. NB. half the maximum + 7
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](http://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 25 bytes

```rb
:>%[:min,:max|~:/&2|:+&7]
```

Call like `f^[80,32]`. Gives `true` for not creepy, `false` for creepy.

#### Explanation

```rb
    :min                  # the minimum
:>%[    ,               ] # is greater than
         :max|            # the maximum...
              ~:/&2|        # over two...
                    :+&7    # plus 7
```

Comment: This is a beautiful language. I spent a long time trying to accomplish similar ends with Ruby (I called it "Blurb"), but leaning heavily on `method_missing` led to too much complexity. This approach is clean and elegant. Congrats!

Comment: @Jordan thanks! I can't take *all* the credit, as this was heavily inspired by J (hence the name). I'm open to suggestions from a fellow Ruby programmer if you have any.

Comment: @Jordan you should see some of the other more complex J-uby answers. They're quite something.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 26 bytes

```
{$0=$1/2+7>$2||$2/2+7>$1}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@1@tYmCrYqhvpG1up2JUU6NiBGEa1hr@/29ioABEugp@@SUKzkWpqQWVXIYWCkaGqEIWBgrGRkAhmApTBVMDBNfEXMHQAAgQIsbmCsYWqEYYGSkYogoBAA)

Outputs 1 for "Creepy" and 0 for "Not Creepy". Could save 3 bytes if no-output could be consider a falsy value, via:

```
$0=$1/2+7>$2||$2/2+7>$1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift - 33 bytes

```swift
var f={max($0,$1)/2+7>min($0,$1)}
```

A `lambda`-function's equivalent in Swift, but unfortunately cannot take an array :((. Outputs `true` for truthy and `false` for falsy. If one must not count the declaration of the function (Python doesn't) the byte count would be 27. **Usage:** `print(f(age1,age2))`

**[Check it out!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5925e1a785c3fe781a037f73)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 16 bytes

```
{sort|[_<_/2+7]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjBCsMgEATQe76kpQN1dw166J8YkYAEemgDSW6u3250Lm9mjj2vbVtaOffj0pA@6c0vF2v7rd9/mUKwBtZEBPJg6noD4bFnzOO3DmR6ehUH8V1m0JAEJDFq0az58dStpqm2Gw)

This is an anonymous function that takes input as two literals (not an array) from the input stream.

#### Explanation

```
{sort|[_<_/2+7]}                 Anonymous function
 sort                            Sorts the numbers in the input stream
     |[       ]                  And push
       _<                        whether the smaller value  is less than
         _/2+7                   the greater value / 2 + 7
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 21 bytes

```
->*x{x.max/2+7>x.min}
```

Yup.

```
f = ->*x{x.max/2+7>x.min}
f[18,21]  #=> false
f[80,32]  #=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 115 bytes

Edit : Bugfix according to @Alexx Roche

```python
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=a
d=b
if b < a:
 c=b
 d=a
if not c < d/2.0+7:
 print("Not ",end='')
print("Creepy")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTKwmVm2ybyJVim8SVmaaQpGCjkGjFpZAM5CqkAMWBYnn5JQrJQPEUfSM9A21zoGxBEUi/kh9QQkknNS/FVl1dkwsq6FyUmlpQqaT5/7@hKZeFwb/8gpLM/Lzi/wA)

Comment: This answer is far from golfed. For example, you can right your `if` statements all on one line, remove excess whitespace in all your comparisons, take the input as simply `a,b=eval(input())`. Furthermore there are many changes in the algorithm you're using that could make it shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## z-shell (zsh), 38 bytes

```
n=(${(no)@});echo $((n[2]/2+7-n[1]>0))
```

`${(no)@}` is a numeric sort of the argument array

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 34 + 2 (-ap) = 36 bytes

```perl
$_=$F[0]/2+7>$F[1]|$F[1]/2+7>$F[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbFLdogVt9I29wOyDKMrQGTML5B7P//xgYKlgb/8gtKMvPziv/r@prqGRga/NdNLAAA)

Answer (score 1):

### BASH, 135 bytes

I dabbled in this area a [few years ago](http://www.alexx.net/2012/01/match-making-age-ranges.html). I think that [Greg Martin's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122520/is-this-relationship-creepy#comment300579_122520) point should factor in, and wonder how he picked 13 and not, (for example) 12 as 13 is the upper bound of x < x/2+7. Leo what is the test cases for [14,21], [15,15] and [16,21]?

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $1 -lt $2 ]&&./$0 $2 $1&&exit
[ $(($1+$2)) -ge $(((($1-$2)/2)**2)) ]&&[ $((((($2*10)+5)/19)+7)) -lt $2 ]&&echo -n 'Not ';echo Creepy
```

(could save bytes by using ✗ for "Creepy" and ✓ for "Not Creepy" or exit codes)

Answer (score 1):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 25 bytes

```lua
lt(min(a,b),max(a,b)/2+7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z@nRCM3M08jUSdJUyc3sQLM0DfSNtf8//@/keF/I0sA)

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, 14 Bytes

```
:{:{(?r2,7+)n;
```

Pretty simple, but I don't see any obvious ways to cut down on characters.

#### Explanation:

```
               | Assume input is on the stack
:{:{           | Duplicate items on the stack (we pop them for inequality testing)
    (?r        | Sort them, so that the larger is on top of the stack
       2,7+    | Divide top item by 2 and add 7
           )n; | Print the truthy value of younger > (older/2) + 7
```

Prints 1 for non-creepy relationships, 0 for creepy ones

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 8 bytes

```
L,#2/7+>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HR9lI31zb7v///4am/00NAA)

2 bytes off Jelly just feels weird

### How it works

```
L,   - Lambda function
     - Example arguments: [15 50]
  #  - Sort;      STACK = [15 50]
  2/ - Halve;     STACK = [15 25]
  7+ - Add 7;     STACK = [15 32]
  >  - Greater;   STACK = [1]
```

Comment: I see no output when I run it.

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer That's because it's an anonymous function. You need to actually call it to get output, which you can do with the `-i` flag: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HR9lI31zb7v///4am/00N/uUXlGTm5xX/180EAA "Add++ – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 28 bytes

```
&:&:00p`00g\> #0 #\_\7-2*`.@
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X81KzcrAoCDBwCA9xk5B2UBBOSY@xlzXSCtBz@H/fyNDBSNLAA)

Since Befunge uses integer math, I flipped it and added 7 to the minimum then multiplied by 2. 1 = Creepy, 0 = Not creepy

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
Đ↔₂7+≥Π
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRHbVMeNTWZaz/qXHpuwf//0UaGOkYmsQA)

Takes input as an array of integers

Explanation:

```
       Implicit input [x,y]
Đ      Duplicate the array  [x,y],[x,y]
↔      Flip the top array   [x,y],[y,x]
₂      Divide the top of the stack by 2    [x,y],[y/2,x/2]
7+     Add 7 to each element of the top of the stack    [x,y],[y/2+7,x/2+7]
≥      Is the second on the stack greater than or equal to the top elementwise [x>=y/2+7,y>=x/2+7]
Π      Take the product (auto-casts to integers)
       Implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Æ╠àá;╚
```

[Run and debug online](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=92cc85a03bc8&i=[40,+40]%0A[18,+21]%0A[80,+32]%0A[15,+50]%0A[47,+10000]%0A[37,+38]%0A[22,+18]&a=1&m=2)

Here's the ungolfed ascii representation of the same program.

```
oE  sort inputs and push each to stack, now the larger age is on top of the stack
^h  increment larger age and integer divide by 2
7+  add 7
<   is the first number less than the second?
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=oE%09sort+inputs+and+push+each+to+stack,+now+the+larger+age+is+on+top+of+the+stack%0A%5Eh%09increment+larger+age+and+integer+divide+by+2%0A7%2B%09add+7%0A%3C+%09is+the+first+number+less+than+the+second%3F&i=[40,+40]%0A[18,+21]%0A[80,+32]%0A[15,+50]%0A[47,+10000]%0A[37,+38]%0A[22,+18]&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 bytes

```
n v <U/2+7
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=biB2IDxVLzIrNw==&input=LW1SIFsKWzQwLDQwXSwKWzE4LDIxXSwKWzgwLDMyXSwKWzE1LDUwXSwKWzQ3LDEwMDAwXSwKWzM3LDM4XSwKWzIyLDE4XSwKWzEzLDEzXSwKWzIxLDI5XQpd)

Takes a 2-element array as input.

#### How it works

```
Un v <U/2+7

Un  Sort the input
v   Pop the first element (smaller one)
<   less than...
U/2+7  Implicitly cast the remaining 1-length array to number (larger one)
       then calculate /2+7
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
sh½7+⁰t≥
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwic2jCvTcr4oGwdOKJpSIsIiIsIlsyMCwyMV0iXQ==)

Inputs are a 2 element list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
F·>o+7½O
```

Takes input as a 2-element list

```
F·>o+7½O
       O  sort
F         fold / apply following binary function to the elements
 · o+7½   apply this to the second argument
      ½   halve
   o+7    then add 7
  >       compare
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3@3Qdrt8bfNDe/3///8fbWSkY2gRCwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 20 bytes

```arturo
$=>[>7+0.5*do sort&]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?rKHbjz)

```
$=>[       ; a function where input is assigned to &
    sort&  ; sort input
    do     ; dump both ages from input list onto the stack
    0.5*   ; multiply TOS (the higher age) by 0.5
    +7     ; add 7 to TOS
    >      ; is NOS greater than TOS?
]          ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 60 bytes

```powershell
$c={param($a,$b)[math]::max($a,$b)/2+7-gt[math]::min($a,$b)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCoMwEEX3fsUsskjotE18EBGEbvsN4iKVtEqNEbUPEL89jdT2bs7cOcz09qWHsdZt6xyp8rlXgzKUKCQXVhg11WWWGfXeNsdwJ/e36S@abhOLP7amf0wacjhRGnOMOUMqUgzFSvllyjEK155gsvpYouA@fowkRiljwdUOWlU1UDJC08HvL5sD8CHV4dw97V17XfASwUOULFic@wA)

No doubt could be improved upon!

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 42 bytes

```
    $c={param($a,$b)$a/2+7-gt$b-or$b/2+7-gt$a}
```

Rather than using `[math]::min` and `::max`, I'm trying both `$a` vs `$b` and `$b` vs `$a` then -or the result.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 28 Bytes

Anonymous immediate window function that tTakes age inputs from cells `[A1]` and `[B1]` as expected type `Integer` and outputs a `Boolean` value representing creepyness to the VBE immediate window

```vba
?[B1]/2+7>[A1]|[A1]/2+7>[B1]
```

Comment: Can't you just write this as a formula in a cell?

Comment: @Neil, yes I <s>could</s> have, though my particular purpose in golfing with VBA is more to keep some level of practice up with the language, rather than optimizing for the byte count

Comment: Ah yes, VBA is a slightly different language.

Answer (score 0):

## [shortC](//github.com/aaronryank/shortC), 21 bytes

```
D(a,b)a/2+7<b|b/2+7<a
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 30 bytes

```
~:>:|c=a┘d=b\c=b┘d=a]?d>=c/2+7
```

Explanation

```
           First, we mustsort the input parameters
~:>:       IF a (from cmd line) > b (from cmd line)
|c=a┘d=b   THEN set c and d
\c=b┘d=a   ELSE set c and d in the other way
]          END IF
?d>=c/2+7  PRINT -1 if d is higher than c's lower bound, 0 for creepy
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, <s>17</s> <s>16</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
>+7/.)JSQ2hJ
```

Takes a list. Outputs True for creepy, False for not creepy.

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3E%2B7%2F.%29JSQ2hJ&input=%5B80%2C40%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B40%2C40%5D%0A%5B18%2C+21%5D%0A%5B80%2C+32%5D%0A%5B15%2C+50%5D%0A%5B47%2C+10000%5D%0A%5B37%2C+38%5D%0A%5B22%2C+18%5D&debug=0)

#### explanation

```
>+7/.)JSQ2hJ
      JSQ        # Sort the input list (Q) and store the result in J
    .)           # pop the last/largest element from J (lets call it x)
          hJ     # the first/only element of J (lets call it y)
>+7/     2       # 7 + x/2 > y
```

### old approach, 13 bytes

```
s.b<Y+7/N2_QQ
```

Takes a list. Outputs 1 for creepy, 0 for not-creepy.

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s.b%3CY%2B7%2FN2_QQ&input=%5B80%2C40%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B40%2C40%5D%0A%5B18%2C+21%5D%0A%5B80%2C+32%5D%0A%5B15%2C+50%5D%0A%5B47%2C+10000%5D%0A%5B37%2C+38%5D%0A%5B22%2C+18%5D&debug=0)

#### explanation

```
s.b<Y+7/N2_QQ
 .b       _QQ        # map over the list and it's reversal (variables: Y,N)
   <Y+7/N2           # Y < N/2 + 7
s                    # sum: False + False = 0; True + False = 1 (; True + True = 2 can never occur, because one of the ages is always larger or equal)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 10 bytes

```
q~$~2d/7+<
```

Takes input as a list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19Yp1JnlKJvrm3z/3@0kZGCoUUsAA)

#### Explanation

```
q~          e# Read and eval input.
  $         e# Sort the list.
   ~        e# Dump the list on the stack.
    2d/7+   e# Apply age/2+7 to the greater age.
         <  e# Check if the other age is less than that.
```

Comment: Do you need the `d`? all the test cases work without it.

Comment: @Challenger5 OP said not to round if the age is an odd number, so I assume so.

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 12 bytes

```
;RZ⌠i½7+≤⌡Mπ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@28dFPWoZ0Hmob3m2o86lzzqWeh7vuH//2gjIx1Di1gA), or [run all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#e9Sz4L91UNSjngWZh/aaaz/qXPKoZ6Hv@Yb/ICrzf3S0iYGOiUGsTrShhY6RIZC2MNAxNgLxTXVMQeIm5jqGBkAAZBqb6xhbAGkjIx1Di9hYAA)!

Outputs `1` if it's not creepy, and `0` if it is.

Explanation:

```
;RZ⌠i½7+≤⌡Mπ  implicit input: [a, b]
;RZ           zip input with its reverse ([[a,b], [b,a]])
   ⌠i½7+≤⌡M   for each pair:
    i           flatten
     ½7+        half of one plus 7
        ≤       is less than or equal to the other?
           π  product (acts as a boolean AND)
```

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, <s>17</s> 16 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{(x&y)<7+.5*x|y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1qjQq1S08ZcW89Uq6KmsjbayMja0CL2/38A) (**oK** rather than **q/kdb+**)

**Examples:**

```
q){(x&y)<7+.5*x|y}[22;18]
0b
q){(x&y)<7+.5*x|y}[22;17]
1b
```

**Explanation:**

Outputs creepy as boolean 1b (true, creepy) or 0b (false, not creepy)

```
{(x&y)<7+.5*x|y} / solution
{              } / lambda function with implicit parameters x and y
            x|y  / max of x and y
         .5*     / multiply by 0.5 (aka divide by 2)
       7+        / add 7
      <          / less than?
 (x&y)           / min of x and y
```

**Notes:**

Polyglot in:

- q/kdb+
- K
- oK (see TIO link)

Answer (score 0):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), <s>21</s> 18 bytes

```
/o
\i@/sh2:-6-.H+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/nysm00G/OMPIStdMV89DO@//f0MLHQUjIwA)

-3 bytes thanks to Martin Ender.

Input is in any format that includes exactly two integers.  Output is `1` if creepy and `0` if not creepy.

#### Explanation

```
ish2:-6-.H+no

i                Input numbers
 s               Sort the two ages
  h2:            Divide larger age by 2 rounded up
     -           Subtract from smaller age
      6-         Subtract 6
        .H+      Determine whether result is negative
           n     Push 1 if was negative, 0 otherwise
            o    Output
```

Comment: Would it be possible to shorten the formula by sorting the inputs with `s` (which puts the max on top and the min below)?

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 59

```
scan $argv %d\ %d x y
puts [expr max($x,$y)/2+7>min($x,$y)]
```

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMYTJ3ckNQS0syZTA)

To try, type

`tclsh main.tcl Age1 Age2`

on the green area.

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl, 44

I was losing to answers implementing it as a function, so I had to make mine into a function also:

```
proc c x\ y {expr max($x,$y)/2+7>min($x,$y)}
```

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcUpvRDBXaEtZY0k) — You just have to press on the "Execute" button and see the 0 and 1 digits on the green area matching the question's creepiness values.

Answer (score 0):

## Wolfram Language, 16 bytes

```
Min@#<Max@#/2+7&
```

Takes input as a list.

Answer (score 0):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 64 bytes

```
readIO
j=i
readIO
x=i/2+7-j
y=j/2+7-i
if x c
if y c
print k
lblc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/silos#@1@Umpji6c@VZZvJBWVW2GbqG2mb62ZxVdpmgVmZXJlpChUKySCqEkgVFGXmlShkc@Uk5ST////f0Pi/oQkA)

It prints out the letter "k" if the relationship is ok, otherwise it prints out nothing. I couldn't figure out any mathemagical way with standard mathematical operators to do an if x>0 pr y>0 to save bytes.

---

Alternatively, we can create an "or gate" by exploiting the fact that x^.5 will error out if the number is negative.This removes the need for a conditional, but lengthens our code. This version outputs 0 for creepy and some positive number for not creepy.

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 67 bytes

```
readIO
j=i
readIO
x=0-i/2-7+j
y=0-j/2-7+i
a=x^.5+y^.5+1
printInt a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/silos#@1@Umpji6c@VZZvJBWVW2BroZuob6ZprZ3FVAtlZYHYmV6JtRZyeqXYliDDkKijKzCvxzCtRSOT6//@/kcV/I0MA)

Answer (score 0):

## MATL, 10 bytes

```
tEP-X>-14>
```

My first ever solution. :) [Try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8Q1QDfCTtfQxO7//2hjcwVji1gA)!

Explainer:

```
t    % push the input array [a b] (possibly redundant)
EP   % push the flipped(P)+doubled(E) array [2b 2a]
-    % subtract to get [a-2b b-2a]
X>   % take the maximum
-14> % if either exceeds -14, then it is creepy af bro!
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 8 bytes

```
a2/7+Lfp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z/RSN9c2yet4P9/CwMuYyMA)

Explanation:

```
a2/7+Lfp

a        # sort (implicit input)
 2/7+    # halve and add 7
     L   # less than?
      fp # pop value, leaving just the result
         # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### C, C++, Java, C#, D, 56 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
int c(int a,int b){return((a>b?a:b)/2+7)>(a>b?b:a)?1:0;}
```

**C, C++, D optimization : 52 bytes**

```cpp
int c(int a,int b){return((a>b?a:b)/2+7)>(a>b?b:a);}
```

- C++ convert bool object to int implicitly ( false = 0, true = 1 )
- In C, booleans are represented by integers values, where 0 is false, and 1 is true.
- <s>I barely know how to print something in D, so i won't comment about boolean to int conversions in this language</s> Zacharý just informed me that D bool to int conversion works exactly like in C/C++
- Unfortunately, Java and C# can't convert an integer to a boolean, so we need to use ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, 11 bytes

```
⌊<(⌊7+.5×⌈)
```

[Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=80%28%u230A%3C%28%u230A7+.5%D7%u2308%29%2932&run)

Answer (score 0):

### [Sakura](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/sakura), 7 bytes

```
>Ƣ+ħ⓪7ƣ
```

Takes input as an array and outputs -1 if creepy and 0 otherwise.

Explanation:

```
>                     >
 Ƣ      max(         )
  +                +
   ħ             /2
    ⓪       input
     7              7
      ƣ                min(     )
                           input
```

Answer (score 0):

## x86-64 machine code, 16 bytes

Takes the ages in `edi, esi`, returns 0 or 1 in `eax`, following x86-64 SysV ABI for `bool creepy(int, int);`.

```
39 f7 7d 02 87 fe 8d 44  36 f2 29 f8 c1 e8 1f c3
```

Assembly source follows.  We test `2*young - 14 - old < 0`.

```
creepy: 
        cmp     edi, esi        
        jge     ready
        xchg    edi, esi
ready:
        ;;  higher age now in edi
        lea     eax, [rsi*2-14]
        ;; eax = highest age the younger person can date
        sub     eax, edi
        ;; if result is negative, then creepy
        shr     eax, 31
        ret
```

Answer (score 0):

## ARM64 machine code, 24 bytes

Takes the ages in `w0, w1`, returns 0 or 1 in `w0`, following normal ARM64 calling conventions for `bool creepy(int, int);`.  (You could handle 64-bit ages by replacing all `w` with `x` registers, with no increase in size.)

```
4b010402 
4b000423 
3100385f 
3a4ed860 
1a9fd7e0 
d65f03c0
```

Assembly source follows.  We test `x-2*y > -14 || y-2*x > -14`.

```
creepy:
    sub     w2, w0, w1, lsl #1
    sub     w3, w1, w0, lsl #1
    cmn     w2, #14
    ccmn    w3, #14, #0, le     // #0 = none of NZCV, makes gt true
    cset    w0, gt
    ret
```